# Alinear varios elementos de una celda

Tags: html, css

En una celda de una tabla de HTML
Quiero poner en la parte superior izquierda un link
En el centro de la celda una imagen
Y en la parte inferior derecha otro link
Con css
No puedo

Comment: Adjunta tu código

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer [ask]. Luego [edit] tu pregunta y complétala con el código que estás utilizando (un [mcve] quizás) y una idea clara de lo que esperas obtener, si puedes describirlo con palabras, si no quizás una imagen pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="es-CO">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <title>Practica</title>

                <style type="text/css">
                    .container {
                        
                        background-color:  grey;
                        border: 1px solid gray;
                     
                    }
                   
                    .container table{
                        width: 100%;
                        border-collapse: collapse;

                    }

                    table caption {
                        height: 70px;
                        font-size: 34px;
                    }

                    .container #primera-fila {
                        position: relative;
                    
                        background-color: white;
                    }
                    #link-uno {
                        position: absolute;
                        font-weight: bold;          
                        left: 10px;
                        top: 0px;

                    }

                    #img-table {
                      height: 25px;
                      width: 10%;
                      margin: 0 auto;
                      border: none;
                      padding: 5px;

                    }

                    #img-table img {
                        height: 70px;
                        border-radius: 10px;
                        border: 1px solid greenyellow;

                    }

                    #link-dos {
                        position: absolute;
                        bottom: 0;
                        right: 10px;
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }


                </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <div class="container">
                    
                        <table>
                            <caption>Tabla de practica</caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr id="primera-fila">
                                    
                                    <td id="link-uno"><a href="#">Primer Link titulo</a></td>
                                    <td id="img-table">
                                        <img src="./img-gold.jpg" height="45px">
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="link-dos"><a href="#">Otro link</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>


                    </ul>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```